# Why is the Challah braided?

Tags: shabbat, challah-shabbat-bread

Every challah I've seen in my life is braided, regardless the country or customs. But what are the origins of preparing the challah in this way? The bread in the Beit HaMikdash wasn't like this as far as I know.